Cannot Retrieve SharePoint Online List via REST API – Bearer Token Issue
I am trying to retrieve data from a SharePoint Online list using a REST API call, but I am encountering an issue. Here is the code and request structure I am using:
GET https://companyname.sharepoint.com/_api/web/getbytitle('listname')  
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken  
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"

I keep getting an error when making the request. However, the bearer token seems to be correctly generated, as I can retrieve it without any issues.

I have set up permissions in Azure AD (Entra ID), and the application has the necessary API permissions.
The token is generated via the Client Credentials flow.
The request is sent using Postman (or another HTTP client/tool).

What could be causing this issue? Am I missing any specific permissions or headers required by SharePoint Online? Do I need to adjust the request format?
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!


try add admin consent if you have permission.

Couple things to consider.

the endpoint is https://{companyname}.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<listname>')/items
you forgot lists in the uri
the parameters defined in your postman are for query, but they should be header parameters. You can define those in a different tab.


